# Keys on keyboard only work if shift key is pressed

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

In the last weeks I encountered a weird problem on my computer: Two keys i.e. the <kbd>#</kbd> and the <kbd>3</kbd> key only produce an input if they are pressed together with the <kbd>⇧</kbd> key.

Since I use a german Keyboard <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> results in <kbd>§</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> results in <kbd>'</kbd>. Interestingly this problem is not present on the locked screen  where I can enter both keys normally. `xev` gives the following output:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x7a7, subw 0x0, time 5869346, (388,1003), root:(2308,1032),
    state 0x0, keycode 12 (keysym 0x33, 3), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (33) "3"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

And:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  41  0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x7a7, subw 0x0, time 6169284, (386,1007), root:(2306,1036),
    state 0x0, keycode 51 (keysym 0x23, numbersign), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (23) "#"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

For the normally working keys, I don't get the two lines with the numbers.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've submitted some cool formatting to your question, may be interesting for the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key which didn't work earlier was due to the wrong key mapping that I seemed to have entered. To solve the issue I had to reset all shortcuts.